# Outlook Redemption 1st Step Problems

Tags: python, outlook, ole, outlook-redemption

I am trying to work with Outlook Redemption using Python. Currently I am hitting an error just trying to get things working.

```
import win32com.client

session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Redemption.RDOSession")
```

However, I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 3, in <module>
    session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Redemption.RDOSession")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in
Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,c
lsctx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 114, in
_GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 91, in _
GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.II
D_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221233, 'OLE error 0x8004010f', None, None)
```

I am pretty sure that I have Redemption installed correctly, along with MAPI, and the win32com package for python. I've double checked all three of their installations and nothing has changed.

I currently do not have Outlook or Exchange installed on this computer. Could this be the issue?

Has anyone else hit this error before?

Answer (score 0):

The error is `MAPI_E_NOT_FOUND`. Most likely that means the MAPI system (Outlook) is not installed, or that it is of a wrong bitness different from that of your app.

What is the bitness of your app, Windows, and Outlook? Does the follwing apply? http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject

Comment: Thanks. All of my installations were 64-bit, but it still wasn't working. I reinstalled everything at 32-bit and now it is working. I have no idea, but it works now.